# Partial upgrade error

Tags: 11.10, update-manager

this is an issue I have googled a lot and I have tried a lot of fixes, but non of them really worked.

At some point (I can't remember when/how) my Update system sort of broke, and since then it is always complaining about "Not all updates can be installed, run a Partial Upgrade".

[image]

If I click on Partial Upgrade, I get the following result

[image]

But running apt-get install -f does not fix anything, and at the end I always get the following message

[image]

Funny thing is that my apt-get system works perfect on Console. I can update my system through apt-get update, apt-get upgrade etc..

So.. how can I fix the graphic interface? I understand that my apt-get system is not broken, but somehow its GUI it is.

Any thoughts about it?

THANKS!

P.D: I have already tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`

**Edit**: This is the output I get after `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
> dan@dan ~ $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade Ign
> http://archive.canonical.com oneiric InRelease Ign
> http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security InRelease Ign
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease Ign
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates InRelease Ign
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports InRelease Hit
> http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release.gpg Hit
> http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release.gpg Hit
> http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release.gpg Hit
> http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release.gpg         Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release                       Hit
> http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner i386 Packages         Ign
> http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner TranslationIndex         
> Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release             
> Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release           
> Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Sources          
> Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Sources                 
> Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Sources          
> Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Sources            
> Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Sources          
> Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages          
> Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted i386 Packages    
> Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted Sources   
> Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe Sources     
> Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse Sources   
> Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main i386 Packages   
> Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/restricted i386
> Packages Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe i386
> Packages       Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse
> i386 Packages     Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main
> TranslationIndex        Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric/multiverse TranslationIndex  Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric/restricted TranslationIndex Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric/universe TranslationIndex Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-updates/main Sources         Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-updates/restricted Sources   Hit http://security.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-security/universe i386 Packages Hit http://security.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-security/multiverse i386 Packages Hit
> http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main TranslationIndex Hit
> http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse
> TranslationIndex Hit http://security.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-security/restricted TranslationIndex Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe Sources     Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Sources   Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main i386 Packages Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted i386 Packages
> Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe
> TranslationIndex Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-updates/universe i386 Packages Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
> Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main TranslationIndex
> Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse
> TranslationIndex Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-updates/restricted TranslationIndex Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/universe TranslationIndex
> Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/main Translation-en  
> Hit http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse
> Translation-en Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main
> Sources       Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-backports/restricted Sources Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-backports/universe Sources   Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-backports/multiverse Sources Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-backports/main i386 Packages Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-backports/restricted i386 Packages Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe i386 Packages
> Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse i386
> Packages Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main
> TranslationIndex Hit http://security.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-security/restricted Translation-en Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse
> TranslationIndex Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-backports/restricted TranslationIndex Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe
> TranslationIndex Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main
> Translation-en_GB       Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main
> Translation-en          Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric/multiverse Translation-en_GB Hit http://security.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-security/universe Translation-en Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Translation-en    Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Translation-en_GB Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Translation-en Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Translation-en_GB Ign
> http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Translation-en_GB Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Translation-en Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/main Translation-en Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/multiverse Translation-en
> Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates/restricted
> Translation-en Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-updates/universe Translation-en Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/main Translation-en Ign
> http://archive.canonical.com oneiric/partner Translation-en Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/multiverse
> Translation-en Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com
> oneiric-backports/restricted Translation-en Hit
> http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports/universe Translation-en
> Reading package lists... Done Reading package lists... Done Building
> dependency tree        Reading state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0
> newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. dan@dan ~ $
```

Answer (score 1):

Review your software sources, and remove any unused or outdated repositories.

Try one (or more) of these:

```
(remove unmet dependencies)
sudo apt-get -f install

(remove .deb archives from packages no longer installed)
sudo apt-get autoclean

(clear files from Aptitude cache: /var/cache/apt/archives )
sudo apt-get clean
```

Post the output of an update & upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**UPDATED:**

Your active sources should (most likely) not include the 'backport' elements:

This is from my setup: (edited to 'GB', instead 'NZ')

```
(snip)
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Whereas your 'sources' appear to be: (or equiv.)

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

These should also NOT say '**oneiric**-backports' !?

Comment: I did all you said, and I have updated the question with the output. As you can see, everything looks fine in console, but then GUI complains about "Partial upgrade".

Comment: Do you know why you have so many sources (including backports) included?  Unless these are needed, this may be at least part of cause ..

Comment: Can you point me to a "default" sources for oneiric? I cannot find them. Thanks

Comment: _Default /etc/apt/sources.list for Ubuntu 11.10 GB/UK_ https://gist.github.com/1379433

Comment: That's the one I am using... :(

Comment: back to my answer.

Comment: Should be no reason to autoclean and clean - apt-get clean will remove them all - including those that autoclean would have.