# How to safely remove or repair plymouth package?

Tags: apt, updates, plymouth

I have a broken package... So far nothing horrible. The problem is that it is Plymouth, and it seems that if I remove it, I will remove half of the packages of my system... So here is my question: if I actually remove, or even purge **plymouth**; will I at least have a terminal left after it to reinstall it? Or am I definitely doomed?

Just to illustrate what I say; here is the result of an

> apt-get --reinstall install plymouth:

```
julien@julien-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install plymouth
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of plymouth is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 plymouth : Depends: libdrm-nouveau1 (>= 2.4.11-1ubuntu1~) but it is not installable
            Recommends: plymouth-themes-all but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

or an

> apt-get -f install

(well basically it is the same)

```
julien@julien-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for julien: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 plymouth : Depends: libdrm-nouveau1 (>= 2.4.11-1ubuntu1~) but it is not installable
            Recommends: plymouth-themes-all but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
julien@julien-desktop:~$
```

Any idea would be very welcome...

Comment: PS: if someone want to know how that possibly happened... Well, I more or less have the problem since installation (yesterday): system didn't want to perform full update (see thread [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80895/partial-upgrade-error/120390#120390) ). After one day I decided to take care of the pb: python was one of the reluctant packages, said it had conflicts with an other package when upgrading, so I tried to upgrade using --force-overwrite... and here I am.

Comment: So.. Have you searched for the dependencies to manually install them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to remove it. The [bug report #556372](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/556372) describes the problem. Dave Lentz has a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~dtl131/+archive/mediahacks) which works around those issues. So you have to add the PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dtl131/mediahacks
sudo aptitude update
```

Now you have to update `mountall` to version (as of April 2012): 2.25ubuntu2~mediahacks1. When this is finished you can deinstall plymouth without deinstalling half of your system.

Comment: Looks like it worked!!! You save my life (well, let's say momentously saved me from depression at least :p)! After spending my weekend at work installing stuff, I did not want to have to redo the same on my working time!

Comment: Nice to hear. :-) So you might want to accept my answer, so that other users easily see that it also could help them.